# MYSQL not returning count results for join after adding date filter

Tags: mysql

I am looking to return results that count the number of posts for certain users within a specified date range.

I have gotten as far as counting and listing the top ten users by posts...

```
SELECT ipb_members.name AS "Name", COUNT(ipb_posts.pid) AS "Total Posts"
FROM ipb_posts, ipb_members
WHERE ipb_posts.author_id=ipb_members.member_id
GROUP BY ipb_members.name
ORDER BY CAST(COUNT(ipb_posts.pid) AS SIGNED) DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

However, when I add in the extra where clause to filter by date, I don't get any results back.

```
SELECT ipb_members.name AS "Name", COUNT(ipb_posts.pid) AS "Total Posts"
FROM ipb_posts, ipb_members
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(ipb_posts.post_date,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2014-1-1' AND '2014-1-30'
AND ipb_posts.author_id=ipb_members.member_id
GROUP BY ipb_members.name
ORDER BY CAST(COUNT(ipb_posts.pid) AS SIGNED) DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

I certainly appreciate any help, thanks!

edit: I've done some additional testing and when I expand the date filter to include multiple years, it returns accurate results....so I'm thinking there's an issue with the "between" statement.

Comment: Are you doing string comparisons on the data? I'm not familiar with MySQL date literal format or that specific function.

Comment: I've done some additional testing and when I expand the date filter to include multiple years, it returns accurate results....so I'm thinking there's an issue with the "between" statement.

Comment: Try changing your dates to `'2014-01-01'`  and `'2014-01-30'` even though I don't think it should matter with that particular range.

Comment: wow, that was it man....post the answer below so I can bump it....nice work!

Answer (score 0):

Your conditions in your `WHERE` clause got confused. Try grouping each of them with parentheses. See below:

```
 SELECT 
      ipb_members.name AS "Name", 
      COUNT(ipb_posts.pid) AS "Total Posts"
 FROM ipb_posts, ipb_members
 WHERE (FROM_UNIXTIME(ipb_posts.post_date,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-01-30')
    AND (ipb_posts.author_id=ipb_members.member_id)
 GROUP BY ipb_members.name
 ORDER BY CAST(COUNT(ipb_posts.pid) AS SIGNED) DESC
 LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I'm getting the same result, however, I've done some additional testing and when I expand the date filter to include multiple years, it returns accurate results....so I'm thinking there's an issue with the "between" statement.

Comment: Try to remove the single quotes in your dates.

Comment: Without the quotes it would evaluate to 2012 and 1983.

Comment: dates needed to be formatted to     2014-01-01', thanks again for your help...adding the parenthesis is sound advice no matter what

Answer (score 0):

It's doing a string comparison. Change the dates to '2014-01-01 and '2014-01-30'.